# Android java - correct conversion of String "2013/12/17" to UNIX's timestamp

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I have a DatePicker and result I store back to TextView which is pressed to call a DatePicker Dialog. The text on this TextView is something like  "2013/12/17"

Here's the code :

```
String str_date=greenTvDatePicker.getText().toString();
                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
                Date date = null;
                try {
                    date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);
                } catch (ParseException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } 
                int timestampGreen= (int)date.getTime()/1000;
```

But the result is wrong.

How do I convert such string to a correct UNIX's timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Missing Fact: Time Zone

The answers [by Andru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627591/642706) and [by Prabhakaran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627578/642706) are both partially correct. Like the question they are wrong in that they ignore **the issue of time zone**.

- If you meant [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)/GMT time, you should have said so.
- If you meant the date in a local time zone, then both answers are incorrect.

### Joda-Time

Here is some example code in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

The first part works if you intended UTC. The second part works if you intended a local time zone. I used [Kolkata time zone](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=54) arbitrarily as an example.

The calls to [`withTimeAtStartOfDay()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) are probably superfluous in this example. But such calls are a good practice because they make the code self-documenting about your intention to focus on the day itself as opposed to some particular time of day.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy/MM/dd");
String string = "2013/12/17";

// Assuming the date is in UTC.
DateTime dateTimeInUtc = formatter.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC ).parseDateTime( string ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
long secondsSinceUnixEpoch_dateTimeInUtc = ( dateTimeInUtc.getMillis() / 1000 ); // Convert milliseconds to seconds.

// Assuming the date is in Kolkata (formerly known as Calcutta India).
DateTimeZone kolkataTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTime dateTimeInKolkata = formatter.withZone( kolkataTimeZone ).parseDateTime( string ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
long secondsSinceUnixEpoch_dateTimeInKolkata = ( dateTimeInKolkata.getMillis() / 1000 ); // Convert milliseconds to seconds.
```

When run…

```
dateTimeInUtc: 2013-12-17T00:00:00.000Z  Seconds: 1387238400
dateTimeInKolkata: 2013-12-17T00:00:00.000+05:30  Seconds: 1387218600
```

Comment: well , the problem was in (int) when I made long l=date.getTime()/1000;  int timestampGreen= (int)l; everything became correct. But thank you

Comment: (a) The matter of `int` versus `long` is one of many good reasons to use a decent library rather than do your own date-time calculations. (b) Despite your `long` fix, your code is still broken because of ignoring time zone (unless yours is a rare app that presents UTC/GMT date-times to a user). (c) Glad you are making it work.

Comment: Yep, the time zone reference is important. Otherwise the whole conversion is pointless, therefore my upvote.

Answer (score 3):

Unix time is in seconds you need to multiply 1000 to it.

```
long timestampGreen= (date.getTime()/1000) *1000;
```

and

the date "`2013/12/17`” should be formated like this `yyyy/MM/dd`

change

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
```

to

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

note:

> Use long instead of int for calculating timestamp

Comment: well , the problem was in (int) when I made long l=date.getTime()/1000;  int timestampGreen= (int)l; everything became correct. But thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
String str_date="13-09-2011";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date); 
System.out.println("Today is " +date.getTime());
```

The above code will return you something like this: `1312828200000`  and this is long value.